# Get Specific Row From Table Type With my Filter Values

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have procedure like as below:

```
cursor my_cursor is 
select  first_column, second_column, third_column from table_name;

TYPE my_cursor_type is TABLE OF my_cursor_type%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY INTEGER; 
my_cur  my_cursor_type;

TYPE table_type IS TABLE OF table_name%ROW_TYPE  INDEX BY BINARY INTEGER; 
table_obj  table_type; 

begin 

open my_cursor; 
loop
fetch my_cursor bulk collect 
into my_cur limit 5000;
exit when my_cursor%notfound; 
for i in 1 .. my_cur.count loop   
       table_obj(i).first_column  := my_cur(i).first_column; 
       table_obj(i).second_column := my_cur(i).second_column;   
       table_obj(i).third_column := my_cur(i).third_column;  
     end loop;
  end loop;
  Close my_cursor;

……
```

Now after these codes ı have table_obj which has 100000 record. And this table object has first_column, second_column, third_column.

I search one record's third_column in table_obj. I know first_column, second_column, and i search third_column  in table_obj. I must fetch row from table_obj rows. This searched row has my  first_column, second_column  values. 
And i get third_column_value from this row. How can i get specific row from table_obj rows with plsql ?

Comment: Why are you using the loop to populate your PL/SQL table - why not do a single bulk-collect into `table_obj`? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do with your 'filter values though, or where they're coming from. If you only need the data which matches your specific first/second column values, why aren't you filtering as part of the cursor query?

Comment: I don't know , how can i assign  single loop. You understand correct. I can't use where condtiton. Because i use table objects other loop. namely first_value and second_value change every loop iteration.

Comment: First i want to fill my table_obj. Because Make select query  in every loop itaration  cause performance problems. First i want to ready data. And then i want to use fetched data in loop fastly.

Comment: as a side note, have a  look here why you will be missing records the way you coded the loop: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CWS9H46VW6EN764N4KFI8ZWA5.html. Statement 4 is what you did and next to it is an explanation why this does not work and there are also working examples on that page. HTH KR Peter

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by transforming the first two columns to a single index. Concatenation with a separator works best for that. The separator should be a Character that is not used in either of the first two columns.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR my_cursor
   IS
      SELECT first_column, second_column, third_column FROM table_name;

   TYPE my_cursor_type IS TABLE OF my_cursor_type%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   my_cur           my_cursor_type;

   TYPE table_type IS TABLE OF table_name%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   table_obj        table_type;

   l_composite_idx  VARCHAR2( 61 );
   l_test_idx_1     VARCHAR2( 30 ) := 'Test1';
   l_test_idx_2     VARCHAR2( 30 ) := 'Success';
BEGIN
   OPEN my_cursor;

   LOOP
      FETCH my_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO my_cur LIMIT 5000;

      FOR i IN 1 .. my_cur.COUNT
      LOOP
         l_composite_idx                             := my_cur( i ).first_column || '&' || my_cur( i ).second_column;

         table_obj( l_composite_idx ).first_column   := my_cur( i ).first_column;
         table_obj( l_composite_idx ).second_column  := my_cur( i ).second_column;
         table_obj( l_composite_idx ).third_column   := my_cur( i ).third_column;
      END LOOP;

      EXIT WHEN my_cursor%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE my_cursor;

   -- You access a row in my_cur like this:
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Result: ' || table_obj( l_test_idx_1 || '&' || l_test_idx_2 ) );
END;
```

Hope this helps!